# Show/hide css (checkbox) and js does not restore default image

Tags: javascript, toggle, show-hide

This project correctly shows text from above when the More button is clicked. It will also hide that new text when Less button is clicked. But I can't get the More button to display again in the final resting state. Might be my JS?

```
<nav class="drop-down-menu">
<input type="checkbox" class="activate" id="accordion-1" 
name="accordion-1"><div class="drop-down">
<p class="one-edge-shadow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc faucibus odio. 
Vestibulum neque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
<label for="accordion-1" class="menu-title"><div id="togglthis" 
class="inside-label-div" data-text-swap="Hide">
<img id="imgplus" src="https://i.imgur.com/Z87qmf6.png"></div>
<p class="inside-label-para">The Product includes not only all much can 
be data to sort. Does not include numbers or other pole sidewalk.</p>
</label>
</nav>

var div = document.getElementById("imgplus");
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
if 
(div.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == div.innerHTML) {
div.innerHTML = div.getAttribute("data-text-original");
document.getElementById('imgplus').src  = 
'https://i.imgur.com/Z87qmf6.png';
              } else {
div.setAttribute("data-text-original", div.innerHTML);
div.innerHTML = div.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
document.getElementById('imgplus').src  = 
'https://i.imgur.com/95cB2LZ.png';
}
}, false);
```

A HEAVILY **revised** version [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/keith-purtell/pen/WNErQVo)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this :

```
let div = document.getElementById("imgplus");
    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(div.parentElement.dataset.textSwap === "Show"){
      
      div.parentElement.dataset.textSwap = "Hide";
      this.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/95cB2LZ.png';
      
    }else{
      div.parentElement.dataset.textSwap = "Show"
      this.src= 'https://i.imgur.com/Z87qmf6.png';
    }
});
```

Here we are toggling the data-attribute of parent div between Hide to Show `<div id="togglthis" class="inside-label-div" data-text-swap="Hide">` , and setting the src attr based on its value.

**The problem what I found in your piece of code was , the attribute once set was not changed or reset again , and it kept holding the previous attribute value set.**

Comment: div.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == div.innerHTML , In the provided code snippet , the div.innerHTML is "" (empty ) , so always it will enter into else loop. You might consider looking at this piece of code and managing it

Comment: Ravina, I utilized your advice along with other research, and made extensive changes. The codepen link I'm adding has most of the work done. But it generates a basic script error, that I can't seem to fix ... https://codepen.io/keith-purtell/pen/WNErQVo

Comment: I went through the codepen link provided , however , I couldn't locate the the script error . Can  you give more reference about it? Or may be the steps or where should I look for the error?

Comment: Ravina, there were changes that solved the error. The way I posted this project on StackOverflow was flawed. But, I have not found a way to delete.